# Vertical textview scrolling is not working

Tags: android

`VerticalTextview` scrolling is not working, following is my code snippet :

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
    final boolean topDown;

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        topDown = false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();

        if(topDown){
            canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }

        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

        getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

even I used below snippet for scrolling
`image` is `textview`

```
Textview image = new VerticalTextView(context,null);

     image.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
          image.setSingleLine(true);
          image.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
          image.setSelected(true);
          image.setFreezesText(true);
           image.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem this way :

```
<com.sample.VerticalTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:background="your_background"
        android:text="@string/TestLargeText" />
```

and in your activity:

```
 TextView image = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        image.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

If you do not want to have a spin box, you should set `canvas.rotate(0)` in your `VerticalTextView` class !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean scrolling like in a ScrollView?

You can add large elements to a layout like a LinearLayout and embed the layout in a ScrollView.

Like this for example:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <VerticalTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Imagine a very long text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

(I've shortened the very long text for readability)

[image]

Sorry if I misunderstood :) Hope you can solve it somehow! Anyways, I think an image or sketch of what your TextView looks like right now and what you want it to look/behave like could help understanding this issue.